# generating an array in R with number + i format

Tags: r, arrays

would like to generate an array with each number adds a certain number with below parameters in R:

i<-2

array1<-c(1:100)

and would like to have array like below:

1,3,5,7,9, ...100

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
arrRange <- seq(1,100,by=1)
```

Or for the odd numbers like requested, you'd modify the `by` argument:

```
arrRange <- seq(1,100,by=2)
```